# How to add a font to a web page (for dummies)

Tags: html, css, fonts

I know it's been asked before, only none of the offered solutions seems to function for me. Sorry, I must be doing something wrong, but what?

I'm testing with Chilanka, because it's distinctive enough so I can see at a glance whether I've got this font or whether the browser defaulted to something resembling it.

I downloaded it and copied the Chilanka-Regular.ttf file both to /usr/share/fonts and to the directory containing my index.html file. Now Chilanka functions with kolorpaint (it didn't before), so the .ttf file seems OK.

I tried to include it in the web page :

```
<link href="Chilanka-regular.ttf">

<style>
/*@font-face { 
  font-family: Chilanka-regular; 
  src: url('Chilanka-regular.ttf'); 
} */
@font-face { 
  font: Chilanka-regular; 
  font-family: 'Chilanka-regular';
  src: local("Chilanka-regular.ttf"); 
  url('Chilanka-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
} 

.chilanka-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  /*font-color: green; This syntax is within the <p> tag*/
  color: green;
/*  font: Chilanka-regular; 
  font-family: Chilanka-regular; */
  font-family: 'Chilanka';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
</style>
```

Then I have :

```
<div name="chilanka-text" class="chilanka-text" id = "chilanka-text">
blabla
</div>
```

I shift/reload the page (firefox, but I would like it to function on all browsers)

The colour changes but no Chilanka.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Chilanka is available as an Google Font. See: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Chilanka#standard-styles

Here you can select the font types you want to use and they will give you the correct options to load the fonts in you website `<head>` with `<link` or `@import`. Note that how more fonts and font styles (regular, bold etc) you add the longer it takes the visitor to load you website the first time.

Use CSS rules to specify families like

```
h1,h2,h4 {
font-family: 'Chilanka', cursive;
}
```

**Local (Offline environment)**

If you really need  to use the fonts from your local files because it runs offline also check if the url to the font file is correct `<link href="Chilanka-regular.ttf">` or  `<link href="/Chilanka-regular.ttf">` or `<link href="/fonts/Chilanka-regular.ttf">` etc.

Comment: The google link offers a preview of Chilanka with the sentence "Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.", but it is not displayed in Chilanka. After a few seconds, the page blanks out with the message "Something went wrong".

Comment: Have you installed the font Chilanka to your local machine? I know from experience that webfont's installed on your local machine and used on a website could resulting incorrect font viewing on websites. Because your browser wil look first if you already have the font installed local and uses that font instead of the font from like google.

Especially if the installed font file is not original. Try to uninstall the font from your local machine and try view it in your webbrowser again. Maybe also close your browser first or even restart your system

Answer (score 1):

## Check if the font can load

There can be multiple things going on. your first course of action should be to check weither the font is loading.

depending on how you host/serve your website. there should be an attempt by the browser to request the font. And a response from the server.

you can check this using your browser inspector/developer tools
[image]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: myInvalidFont;
  src: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sansation_light.woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/fascinate/v21/z7NWdRrufC8XJK0IIElS07zR.woff2");
}

.font {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  color: green;
}

.font-invalid {
  font-family: myInvalidFont;
  color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<h1>The @font-face Rule</h1>

<div class="font">this works, so i oooks kinda fancy</div>

<div class="font-invalid">this doesn't load due to cors</div>
```

Once you're certain that the font is loading, you can start to debug the css, or debug why it's not being served.

Include some information of the way you're serving content.
The server technologies differ (apache/iis/kestrel/php). sometimes there's build steps involved (like webpack).

## Make absolutely sure the font is loading

The browser should attempt to load the file.
If its not showing up in the dev-tools network tab.
Move your @font-face rule to the top of your css file. Check if the css 100% valid.

If it does show up, but not as a 200 ok. Resolve the error code displayed, it might be CORS, might be an incorrect path, etc.

**See this gif: it might help you find the issue.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you all. For the moment, I am testing locally, not on a server. I tried putting <link href="Chilanka-regular.ttf"> in <head> instead of <body>, didn't help. I'll try the rest tomorrow.

Comment: ">> testing locally"
do you mean opening the html from your filesystem in the browser? 
If that's the case I would recommend to start a local web server. IE. xamp,, nginx,  node & express, serving from iis pointing to your local folder.  your browser is most likely requesting the font file. and your file system will not automaticly serve a font. you would need a server for that, (even locally)

Comment: Lars, you say "your file system will not automatically serve a font". If the web page asks for a picture, the file system sends the pictures (baring permission problems). What's special about a font file???

Comment: I tried on the server (virtual apache hosted at gandi). No Chilanka. From now on, I'll try both when testing, locally and on the server.

Comment: I should have stressed the point more that the file should show in the network tab. I've added a gif that might be helpful for your to debug things on your end.  with regards to serving from your local machine. It should work fine. I'm just taking some precautions in my answer. There's a lot of differences in the development setups and i'm trying eliminate unknowns.   Serving from a webserver (running locally or somewhere else) would be more common nowadays. More often than not it's an issue on the webserver.  Not the font/css files.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation 4 months ago I tried to download a font and run it locally before (google font lobster) and it didn't work, Try to use the URL provided or the CDN provided instead of downloading it and running it locally.

Comment: I opened the debbuging console and clicked "Network" and then "Font". 
It said : Perform a request or reload the page to see detailed information about network activity." or "Click on the button to start performance analysis". Nothing about fonts. I clicked around but couldn't find the font info. Told you I was dumb. 

BTW, is .ttf OK or should I use .woff? (I've got .eot, .woff and .woff2).

Comment: When I do the same on the remote file, it says "no request".